# how to find Age from DOB in Athena?

Tags: sql, datetime, presto, amazon-athena, date-arithmetic

Here is my query to find out age from the DOB column :

```
date_format (current_timestamp, '%Y_%m_%d') - date_format (c.memberdob, '%Y_%m_%d') as age
```

I am getting following error:

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 4:47: '-' cannot be applied to varchar, varchar

Appreciate your help!

Comment: `date_format` returns a string so you're trying to subtract two strings. instead subtract the dates first, and convert the result to string. something like: `date_format(current_timestamp - c.memberdob, '%Y_%m_%d')`

Comment: @pault my memberdob has a timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to solve this using [function `DATE_DIFF()`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html). From the documentation:

> `date_diff(unit, timestamp1, timestamp2)` → `bigint`
>
> Returns `timestamp2 - timestamp1` expressed in terms of unit.

Try:

```
DATE_DIFF('year', c.memberdob, current_timestamp) as age
```